# How to compute tangents in webgl

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I have an obj model which itself doesn't define tangents. When I load the model I get an object with two children, one has the `geometry` property undefined, the other has a geometry but it doesn't have the tangents, and if I try to compute the tangents I get an error because it doesn't have `uv` mapping:

> TypeError: uv is undefined
>   uvA = uv[ ua ];

I wonder if there's a different way to compute the tangent, without uv mapping. Or maybe I can compute it directly in the shader? Any guess?

Comment: By tangents, are you referring to the tangent and "binormal" (bitangent) vectors used to define the tangent space basis? Those are generally computed from the normal, and the change in S and T texture coordinates at a point on a surface (and despite the name "binormal", very often it is not perpendicular to the normal... I cannot tell you how much I hate that term). If you have a parametric surface, you can compute them in a shader but otherwise you are going to at least need the texture coordinates. You may need partial derivative hardware support, which GL ES 2.0 does not guarantee.

Comment: Yes, I need to convert a vector from TBN to local space coordinates. Is there a way to compute it in javascript?

Comment: Without the texture coordinates (uv mapping) this really cannot be done. I actually cannot understand why you would need a tangent space basis if you do not have texture coordinates in the first place. The most common use is for bump mapping, but if you do not have texture coordinates it will be impossible to map a bump map onto the surface.

Comment: I need the tangent space basis because I am implementing a model that has a parameter that is computed in TBN space. I can load a texture, but once loaded the texture (I have the uv vector in the fragment shader, passed from the vertex shader with a varying variable), how do I compute the tangent in the fragment shader?